# Does Kubernetes installation always needs Docker?

Tags: docker, installation, kubernetes, runtime, cloud-bare-metal

I have two questions regarding running Kubernetes on bare-metal say "Fedora"

1) Does Running Kubernetes always need Docker on bare-matel?

2) Can we run it using  [cri-o](http://cri-o.io/) which provides a CRI compliant runtime for kubernetes on bare-matel?

3) What are the other OCI-compliant alternatives to Docker-Demon that Kubernetes can work with on bare-matel.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, kubernetes only had support for docker as the `container runtime`.

A second option was added (not sure which version) to use `rkt` as the runtime instead of docker.

As of version 1.9, `OCI` (`open container initiative`) runtimes support has been added in beta, allowing for a whole list of new container runtimes to be supported such as:

- bwrap-oci
- crun
- railcar
- rkt
- runc
- runxlc

So the answers are:

1) no, if you choose kubernetes > 1.9 you can choose from a variety of container runtimes

2) yes, kubernetes 1.9+ has cri-o support

3) see the list above

A more detailed explanation here: https://joejulian.name/post/kubernetes-container-engine-comparison/

Comment: Thanks for the information @whites11, however whatever Kubernetes-installation guides/references I found somehow mentioned pre-requisite to have docker installed on the system. So if i chose `Kubernetes > 1.9`  will I still need docker to **INSTALL** Kubernetes?  Can you provide a link/reference to a kubernetes installation-guide where they provide details on how to install kubernetes without docker.

Comment: It really depends on how you install kubernetes. Kubeadm uses docker (this means the control plane components and kubelet are deployed as docker containers). I am not aware of any automated k8s deployment tool that doesn't make use of docker for the control plane, but this guide uses the binaries directly: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way